# Where can I find information about inbuilt registry keys for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-registry, documentation, ossec

Is there a resource for looking up the description and/or usage of W2K8 R2 registry keys?
I need to understand integrity checksum change messages appearing in OSSEC logs on Amazon EC2 instances.

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Epoch`

Firewall related?

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`

What could be changing interface settings? Does it get updated every reboot? During use?

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ASP.NET_2.0.50727\Names`

PIDs of worker processes. Seems legit.

The list goes on - I'd like to be able to look up and find out about any registry entry that changes. The alerts are useless if I can't understand them.

Comment: Microsot has fairly detailed registry explanations on Technet and even public knowledgebases.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I've found the [2003 Technet reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778196(WS.10).aspx) listed in [this ticket](http://serverfault.com/questions/5673/good-resources-to-learn-about-the-windows-registry), but not 2008 R2. The Epoch key is not listed in the 2003 reference.